# Boost asio c++ methode Post with ACCESS TOKEN

Tags: c++, boost

I try to send Post request to web server with token access but i receive "400 Bad Request" 
For receive access token all is good (in Get) but for receive other information i can't write correctly the request :

```
        request_stream << "POST "<<path<<"access_token="<<token<<" HTTP/1.0 \r\n";
        request_stream << "Host:" << host << "\r\n";
        //request_stream << "Authorization: Basic "<<token
        request_stream << "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
        request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
        request_stream << "Content-Length: " << json55.length() << "\r\n";
        request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";  //NOTE THE Double line feed
        request_stream << json55;
```

i searched in all documentation of boost asio librairy(c++) but not existing any information about this case

tankhs for help

Comment: Why do you think it's something wrong with Boost.ASIO? Have you tried to do the same with curl?

Comment: i think just this is problem of format request